# AccessViolationException while executing Threading.Thread.Sleep

Tags: sleep, access-violation

We have developed an application that has intensive thread use (+-50 threads) in Vb.Net. From time to time we get an AccessViolationException at a random thread while it is doing a Thread.Sleep().

As far as we know we're no executing unsafe code as all our code is managed. We're using DevExpress controls but we don't know if they have unmanaged code.

At this point I have no clue on what to do to try to debug and fix this error. Any hint would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you happen to have a full stack trace of the exception?  Have you captured a memory dump at the time of the crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not at a Thread.Sleep but with My.Computer.Network.Ping() that sometimes can throw this exception. This is a known bug.